# [PhoneGap]How to preserve session?

Tags: android, cordova

I am a newer in using phonegap.
Could anyone tell me :How to preserve session in phonegap(or use anything else to preserve information)?

Just as what `Asp.net do :Session["user"]="jack"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) sits well alongside Phonegap to provide a nice interface to persistent clientside storage. Though Ram kiran is right and you could use the Phonegap storage API too.